# setActiveSheetIndex not working properly

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to make export xls with 2 worksheets. When I open the generated xls file, it opens directly to the second worksheet, even though I've declared in the code that generates the first worksheet:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
```

This happened after I'd added the following lines in the code that generates the second worksheet.

```
$objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getStyle('A1:E1')->getFont()->setBold(true);

    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(15);
    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getStyle('A:F')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true); 
    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getStyle('B')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true); 
    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(15);
    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(15);
    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(15);
    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);

    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getPageMargins(1)->setTop(1);
    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getPageMargins(1)->setRight(0.75);
    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getPageMargins(1)->setLeft(0.75);
    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getPageMargins(1)->setBottom(1);

    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getStyle('A1:E1')->getFill()
                    ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
                    ->getStartColor()->setRGB('4EE900');
```

If I comment some of the code lines, (as shown in the picture) the active sheet index works fine.

[image]

So, if I remove these lines, it works fine. Any Idea how to fix this to keep first worksheet as the active worksheet?

Comment: How about adding only a single line to check if it works

Comment: I commented some of the lines and works fine, but still I didn't solve the issue. Please check the picture attached. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a new worksheet automatically sets that as the active sheet.

Unless you use `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);` ***after*** creating your second worksheet, then the second sheet will be your active sheet.

And you can always set the active sheet manually just before your save using

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can add new worksheet ?

Comment: @Gulshan - First, you shouldn't ask a question as a comment against  response to a different questions that somebody else has asked

Comment: @Gulshan - Second, why not look at the documentation and examples, and then consider that a method like `createSheet()` might be used to create a new worksheet